# Iterating over command-line argument pairs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a more than 400 coordinates that I want to pass as an argument into a string, but i don't know how to pass the first argument as "lat" and second argument as "lng" and so on for the rest.

Say I was passing in this

```
./test 1 2 3 4
```

I want my output to be

```
coordinate: {lat: 1, lng: 2}
coordinate: {lat: 3, lng: 4}
```

This is what I have so far, but obviously this isn't how it's done.

```
for i in $@
do

    echo "coordinate: {lat: $i, lng: $i}"

done
```

Comment: btw, as an aside, `for i in $@` is actually quite buggy -- it'll treat `./yourscript "one two" "three four"` exactly the same as `./yourscript "one" "two" "three" "four"`. Always quote `"$@"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while (( "$#" >= 2 )); do
  echo "coordinate: {lat: $1, lng: $2}"
  shift 2
done
```

Note that `shift; shift` is in many circles preferred over `shift 2`, as it works even there's only one argument left; `shift 2` is safe above only because we're comparing `$#` to ensure that there will always be two or more arguments.

Comment: Thank you sir, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You do not need a loop:

```
printf "coordinate: {lat: %s, lng: %s}\n" "$@"
```

And rename your script before putting in your path (something like /usr/local/bin), since `test` is a builtin function.

Comment: I'm really embarrassed that I missed this; you're entirely right.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `shift` (but don't do it like this - see comments below):

```
while [ -n "$1" ]
do
    echo "{coordinate: {lat: $1, lng $2}"
    shift 2
done
```

Comment: This treats an empty string the same as a nonexistent argument -- `./scriptname "" "" three four` will never get to the `three`/`four` pair.

Comment: Also, if you have an odd number of arguments, `shift 2` can be a noop (returning a nonzero exit status but having no effect at all, leaving the existing value in `$1`), resulting in an endless loop.